# How to find td class and check whether it contains class then I need to show pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table. Once if I click button of browser, I need to get pop up until unless I enter any one data in `td` in table.. So I have class to table as well as to `td`. Now I want to check if table contains `td` then I should get popup or else no.

Td are created dynamically

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if ($('.formFields').find('td.item') || $('.formFields').find('td.sections')) {
    return hi();
  }

};

var hi = function() {
  return "Your work will be lost.";
}
```

```html
<table class="formFields">
</table>
```

Comment: so your code is not working?

Comment: yea.. I am getting popup even if td does not contains in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for length as `.find()` will return `jquery`, so

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      if ($('.formFields').find('td.item').length || $('.formFields').find('td.sections').length) {
        return hi();
      }

    };

    var hi = function() {
      return "Your work will be lost.";
    }
```

Comment: where is your `hi` function defined?

Comment: yea working thank you so much.. I just made a mistake that the item and section of tr class